# Runtime Error. Please give me understanding about what I am doing wrong

Tags: java, compiler-construction, runtime

The runtime error I get is:

```
----jGRASP exec: javac -g Programmmm1.java

Programmmm1.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
      StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(infile.nextLine());
      ^
  symbol:   class StringTokenizer
  location: class Programmmm1
Programmmm1.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
      StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(infile.nextLine());
```

and this is my actual segment, why is it saying that it cannot find symbol? Does it have something to do with my Main?

```
 public static void Display()throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
   {
      Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader("G:\\DataFile.txt")); 
      StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(infile.nextLine());
      StringElement str = new StringElement();

      while(token.hasMoreTokens())
      {
         str.setString(token.nextToken());
         stringList.insert(str);
      }
      stringList.print();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this in your import statement

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
```

**Update**

```
 public static void Display()throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
 {
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader("G:\\DataFile.txt"));
    StringTokenizer token = null;
    String line=null;
    while((line=infile.nextLine())!=null && !"".equals(line.trim()))
    {
        token = new StringTokenizer(line);
        StringElement str = new StringElement();

         while(token.hasMoreTokens())
         {
            str.setString(token.nextToken());
            stringList.insert(str);
         }
    }
    stringList.print();
}
```

Comment: You don't know how hard I am laughing at myself right now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know why when I run it, it only shows the first name in my data file?

Comment: @user3604953 you are reading the first line of the file and initializing the StringTokenizer(infile.nextLine());. To read all lines from the file please use another outer loop.

Comment: will something like this work?  
      int n = stringList.listSize();
      for(int i=0; i<n-1; i=i+2)
      {
         System.out.println(stringList.retrieveAt(i) + " " + stringList.retrieveAt(i+1));
      }